# Why my contract binary does not set?

Tags: web3js, contract-deployment, nodejs, truffle-contract, compilation

My project is in Truffle. I programmed a smart contract and want to deploy it with JavaScript. But the following error occurs:

`Error: Contract error: contract binary not set. Can't deploy new instance. This contract may be abstract, not implement an abstract parent's methods completely or not invoke an inherited contract's constructor correctly`.

I don't know the solution to eliminate this problem.

app.js:

```
var Web3=require('web3');
var contract=require("truffle-contract");
var solc=require("solc");
var web3=new Web3('ws://localhost:8545');
var express=require('express');
var app=express();
var fs=require('fs');
var bodyParser=require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(express.static('E:/Alireza/src/js'));
web3.eth.defaultAccount="0x6Db320B080b956c371c4bC5b00eF74e73bCE7798";
                   .
                   .
                   .
app.post('/send-data', function(q,r){   
    var source2='E:/Alireza/contracts/customer.sol';
    var customercompiled=solc.compile(source2)
    var customerJson="E:/Alireza/build/contracts/customer.json";
    var customerJs=JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(customerJson));
    var customer=new web3.eth.Contract(customerJs.abi, null, {data: 
        ByteCode});

    web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount("0x83Ad536099658519ee6A40A3faCAf3dDcEf6178a","Alireza").then(()=>{console.log("Address unlocked");}).catch(console.error);
    var testContract=contract(customerJson);
        testContract.setNetwork("*");
        testContract.setProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8545");
        testContract.new({from: "0xEfc311bfE4aD02fe77cAa172FbbEe7a3563752C5", 
           gas:2000000, gasPrice:200});
        customer.deploy().send({from: 
           "0xEfc311bfE4aD02fe77cAa172FbbEe7a3563752C5", gas:2000000, 
           gasPrice:200}).then((instance)=>{console.log("Contract mined at 
           "+instance.options.address);
           customerInstance=instance});   
         });
```

The mentioned error occurs in `testContract.new(...)` line.

Contract binary:

```
var ByteCode="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";
```

My contract full code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.12;
import "./customerFinder.sol";
contract customer{
   string public firstname;
   string public lastname;
   uint256 public id;
   bool public KYC;
   uint256 public level;
   string public docsHash;
   uint256 public cost=3 ether;
   uint256 public upcost=3 ether;
   string public bankName;
   address payable[] onboarded;

   function fill(string memory fname, string memory lname ,uint256 iden, string memory KYCresult, uint256 categor, string memory hash, string memory bank) public{
      firstname=fname;
      lastname=lname;
      id=iden;
         if(keccak256(bytes(KYCresult))==keccak256(bytes("تأیید")))
            {
               KYC=true;
            }
     level=categor;
     cost/=(3/categor);
     docsHash=hash;
     bankName=bank;
        onboarded.push(address(uint160(msg.sender)));
        customerFinder(0x9638101cb6571cc3A807A2a4e770Ee040dD0275c).filling(id, address(uint160(address(this))));
     }

   function contribution() public payable {
      if(msg.value==cost/(onboarded.length+1))
         {
            for(uint i=0; i<onboarded.length; i++)
               {
                  onboarded[i].transfer(msg.value/onboarded.length);
               }    
           onboarded.push(address(uint160(msg.sender)));
         }
      }
   function KYC_hash() public view returns(string memory, string memory){
       if(KYC==true)
         {
            return ("تأیید", docsHash);
         }else
             {
                return ("رد تأیید", docsHash);
             }
   }


   function update(string memory fname, string memory lname ,uint256 iden, string memory KYCresult, uint256 categor, string memory hash, string memory bank) public {
      firstname=fname;
      lastname=lname;
      id=iden;
         if(keccak256(bytes(KYCresult))==keccak256(bytes("تأیید")))
           {
              KYC=true;
           }
      level=categor;
      upcost/=(3/categor);
      docsHash=hash;
      bankName=bank;
   }
   function representation() public view returns(string memory, string memory, string memory, string memory, string memory, string memory, string memory){
      return (firstname, lastname, uint2str(uint(id)), uint2str(uint(level)), uint2str(uint(cost)), uint2str(uint(onboarded.length)), uint2str(uint(cost/(onboarded.length+1))));
   }

    function uint2str(uint _i) internal pure returns (string memory ) {
    if (_i == 0) {
        return "0";
    }
    uint j = _i;
    uint len;
    while (j != 0) {
        len++;
        j /= 10;
    }
    bytes memory bstr = new bytes(len);
    uint k = len - 1;
    while (_i != 0) {
        bstr[k--] = byte(uint8(48 + _i % 10));
        _i /= 10;
    }
    return string(bstr);
}
   function() external payable{}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
var testContract = contract(customerJson);
```

To this:

```
var testContract = contract({abi: customerJs.abi, unlinked_binary: ByteCode});
```

Comment: This error showed: `TypeError: this.abi.filter is not a function`.

Comment: For this line: `testContract.new({from: "0xEfc311bfE4aD02fe77cAa172FbbEe7a3563752C5", gas:2000000, gasPrice:200});`

Comment: @A.Kiakojouri: Sorry, see the small update in the answer.