# Which of MyContract.new(...) and MyContract.deploy().send(...) is better to deploy a smart contract?

Tags: contract-deployment

Suppose `MyContract` is the name of the given contract. I tried two commands to deploy that, `MyContract.new(...)` and `MyContract.deploy().send(...)`, and the both worked. So, i interest to know which of them is better and What difference do they make in performance?

Comment: I believe that `MyContract.new` only works under Truffle environment. If you don't mind importing that dependency in your script, app or whatever, then there shouldn't be any difference. Truffle simply wraps `web3.eth.Contract` (or `web3.eth.contract` in earlier versions).

Comment: You also forgot to mention that you've used `truffle-contract` for the first case and `web3.eth.Contract` for the second case. I'm concluding these facts from [your previous question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/82221), but you should make them explicitly visible in this question as well, because they are obviously relevant here.